# Letting multiple lines coincide into one line using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

Situation sketch:

I have multiple utility network cables drawn(purple lines in the figure). These lines are drawn all next to each other since I'm working at the level of an "overview map". The next step is however to draw a technical map, where the cables are more realistic drawn, which is that they all lay on top of each other in 1 trench (red line in the middle)

[image: http://imgur.com/SCgSwRM.jpg]

Is there a tool or a python script that allows me to select all the cables and let them coincide/snap/merge to the trench-line, without losing their properties so that afterwards I can still see that the trench contains 5 cables?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Have you tried the [Snap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/snap.htm) ArcToolbox tool?

Comment: Replace geometry is a part of editing toolbar I believe

Comment: This is simpler solution http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155080/how-to-use-replace-geometry-to-replace-the-selected-feature-with-a-circle

Comment: You could attribute the trench with number of cables and symbolize by this attribute.

Comment: @Midavalo, I tried to use the snap tool; but it gives an error when I try to snap to the trench:
http://imgur.com/62Qwprs
http://imgur.com/NeWgt9d

When I read the description of "Replace Geometry", It does not really give the output I want.

I have now read something about the "Integrate" Tool, maybe I can try use that one?

Answer (score 1):

If your cables have a field which corresponds to the trench number you could carry out a one-to-many join, which would attach the cable information to the trench line (see http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010848).

If it's not coded like that, you could still use a spatial join based on proximity. Both ways you would end up with multiple entries, e.g. each trench would appear three times if there are three cables.

However, the Integrate tool is also a good option if you want to shift the cables themselves, though you'd need to be careful around any junctions.