# Make two lines align with each other

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, alignment

[image]

I have two street data sources, and as you can see, they are not perfectly aligning. However, I need data from both of them, so I wonder if there is a way to make them align perfectly with each other. Also,  I want to fix A due to its accuracy (assume one is called A and the other B), and make B follow the shape of it.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 Advanced License.

Comment: You could 'snap' http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000007000000 them together... you can't easily transfer attributes as there's no guarantee that the line endpoints are the same, i.e. a different number of features.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155080/how-to-use-replace-geometry-to-replace-the-selected-feature-with-a-circle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Replace Geometry to replace the selected feature with a circle](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155080/how-to-use-replace-geometry-to-replace-the-selected-feature-with-a-circle)

Comment: You can try the spatial adjustment tool.  If there are only a few lines you can create transformation links.  If there are several lines with a common attribute, you can use edge matching (part of spatial adjustment).

Comment: You could also use a spatial join with a search radius to get the attributes from B into A.